# OrmLite db.Select not return response

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use Servietack and OrmLite in our project. When the request (Db.Select) is sent, after much time, no response return.

```
       public object Get(GetCategoryNews request)
        {
            var PageCount = 20;
            var skip = (request.Page.GetValueOrDefault(1) - 1) * PageCount;

            var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<GetCategoryNews>(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmm") + skip);
            return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, () =>
            {
            //On this line, waiting and no response
              var status = Db.Select<News>().Skip(skip).Take(PageCount).Select(o => new NewsResponse() {
                    Id = o.Id,
                    CreateOn = o.CreateOn,
                    Description = o.Description,
                    PublishOn = o.PubDate,
                    Title = o.Title
                });
                return status;
            });
        }
```

but when Count request, It work well

```
    var count = Db.Count<News>();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Db.Select<News>()` returns a `List<News>` which downloads your entire table results into an in memory list collection. Since you're trying to page the resultset you need to instead build an `SqlExpression` that OrmLite executes to only return the results you're interested in, e.g:

```
//Create SQL Query
var q = db.From<News>()
          .Skip(skip)
          .Take(PageCount);

var results = db.Select(q); //Executes paged query
return results.Select(o => new NewsResponse {
    Id = o.Id,
    CreateOn = o.CreateOn,
    Description = o.Description,
    PublishOn = o.PubDate,
    Title = o.Title
});
```

Comment: thanks guy, How can I query in nested objects, for example = var q = Db.From<News>()
                .Where(o => o.Feed.Category.CategoryId == 10);

Comment: @AmirHossein Please don't put code in comments, can you ask a new question.

Comment: @AmirHossein That's likely not the answer you want, you can use [Typed Where Expression](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#convenient-common-usage-data-access-patterns).